# Problems with apply method on dataflow pub/sub

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am new at dataflow, and i am trying to write some message to pub/sub when tryin to use the apply method for PubsubIO.writeStrings().to("projects/market-place-sql/topics/emisiones") and it say:
[[image]]

Answer (score 1):

The error is simply a type mismatch. The `apply()` method for the `Pipeline` class accepts a second parameter of the type `PTransform<? super PBegin,OutputT>`.

`PubSubIO.writeStrings().to()` returns a `PTransform<PCollection<T>,PDone>` type. Hence, the type mismatch.

Based on the screenshot of the error, it looks like `p` is a `Pipeline` object. You'll need to first apply an input transform to the `Pipeline` object, which will return a `PCollection`. Then call `apply()` on the `PCollection`.

Example:

```java
p.apply("read from Pub/Sub", PubsubIO.readMessages().fromSubscription("subscription/path"))
 .apply("write to Pub/Sub", PubsubIO.writeStrings().to("topic/path"));

p.run();
```

References: [Pipeline.apply()](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/Pipeline.html#apply-java.lang.String-org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform-), [PCollection.apply()](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/values/PCollection.html#apply-java.lang.String-org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform-)